# A numerical aptitude problem

Tags: combinatorics

I have got [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=Ateb3O90Ex8a6z3MlsE_ZHXty6IX;_ylv=3?qid=20130604103155AATF8Zz) problem that says : Given digits $2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4$ how many distinct $4$ digit numbers greater than $3000$ can be formed.

The options are: $50,51,52,54.$

Is there any way I can logically solve the problem instead of manually counting ?

Also, Almost same problem has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186968/given-digits-2-2-3-3-4-4-4-4-how-many-distinct-4-digit-numbers-greater-than) but I am not satisfied with the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the only allowed numbers have to have either a $4$ or a $3$ in the thousands place.

If it's a $4$, there are three possible digits to put in the remaining three positions. So the number of possibilities here are $3\times 3\times 3 - 1$ ($-1$ to account for the number $4222$ which is not possible).

Similarly if $3$ is in the thousands place, there are $3\times 3 \times 3-2$ possibilties ($3333$ and $3222$ being excluded).

So the total is $27+27-1-2 = 51$.

Comment: thanks a lot.nice explanation.got it.